# Solving differential equation with Variable constans?

Tags: differential-equations, assumptions

How do I solve the following differential equations using Mathematica under the assumptions:

```
If Abs[r[t]]<50 ->A=0.5;B=2;
```

AND

```
 If Abs[r[t]]>50 ->A=2;B=-4;
```

.

```
sol = NDSolve[{r'[t] == A*Sqrt[t] + B*t + Sin[t], 
g'[t] == A + B*Cos[t] + A*r[t], r[0] == 0, g[0] == 0}, {r, g}, {t,
 0, 20}];

ParametricPlot[{r[t], g[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 0.6]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values don't seem to make much sense to me, but you could do it like this:

```
A[x_] := Piecewise[{{0.5, Abs[x] < 50}}, 2]
B[x_] := Piecewise[{{2, Abs[x] < 50}}, -4]

sol = NDSolve[{r'[t] == A[r[t]]*Sqrt[t] + B[r[t]]*t + Sin[t], 
    g'[t] == A[r[t]] + B[r[t]]*Cos[t] + A[r[t]]*r[t], r[0] == 0, 
    g[0] == 0}, {r, g}, {t, 0, 20}];

ParametricPlot[{r[t], g[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 0.6]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]